# Running Multiple functions in python Maya

Tags: python, function, maya

Is there a way you can pass multiple functions through one button for eg:

```
def test1(*args)
    print Hi

def test2(*args)
  print Hello

cmds.button('greetings',label = 'Menu',command = test1 & test2)...?
```

I want to run both the functions through one button command is that possible in python maya..???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way to do it would be to define a new function

```
def test1_test2(*args):
    test1(*args)
    test2(*args)

cmds.button('greetings', label='Menu', command=test1_test2)
```

Comment: @Arnvfx If it helped you solve your problem then please accept the answer by clicking on that tick on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it without defining a new function, you could do something like this:

```
cmds.button('greetings',label = 'Menu', command = lambda:[x() for x in [test1, test2]])
```